# How to store multiple values in one key in an associative array for example Map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

For example, I have an associative array

```
let example = new Map([
    ['ex', '1.1','1.2'],
    ['ex2', '1.1', '1.2']
  ]);
```

How i can get 1.2 from key 'ex'?

Comment: That is not a valid way to create a `Map` entries should be a pair like `[key, value]`. The third data of the arrays will be ignored, you can check if if you do `console.log(...example.entries());`. However, you can try pairs like `[key, [val1, val2]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is like `[['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2']];`. So you need to have both 1.1 & 1.2 inside `value`. You can put both of them inside an object and retrieve using the map key

```js
let example = new Map([
  ['ex', {
    val1: '1.1',
    val2: '1.2'
  }],
  ['ex2', {
    val1: '1.1',
    val2: '1.2'
  }]
]);

let k = (example.get('ex'));
console.log(k.val2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need to place those values in an array, and know the index of the item you want:

```js
let example = new Map([
  ['ex', ['1.1', '1.2']],
  ['ex2', ['1.1', '1.2']]
]);

const [, res] = example.get("ex");

console.log(res);
```

Or, if you just want the value `1.2` from that specific array without the index:

```js
let example = new Map([
  ['ex', ['1.1', '1.2']],
  ['ex2', ['1.1', '1.2']]
]);

const res = example.get("ex").find(e => e == "1.2");

console.log(res);
```